# List all the functions called from a DLL during execution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, window

I have an application which links/loads DLLs at run time. 
I want to list (probably write into a file) all functions that are executed during an application run - from both exe and DLL.

Please note that I cannot modify existing code (e.g. adding `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro) as there are too many functions in source code. 
As am I trying this on X64 platform I cannot use `-Gh` to enable `_penter` as well.

Is there any other way to add a hook (function) which gets executed before/after every function call?

Comment: You may want to try `ltrace`.